Non-ASCII characters are not imported correctly in MetaInformation (Solution for FLAC attached)
When importing meta information of music files, non-ASCII characters are not imported correctly. It seems that only the last byte is imported.
In[1]:= Import["E:\\音乐\\明日方舟\\20240216 - 怀黍离OST\\塞壬唱片-MSR,颜沐宸Ace - 击壤歌.flac","MetaInformation"]
Out[1]= <|Xiph-><|Album->{\.00},Artist->{^ì1G-MSR/¸Ace},RecordingDate->{Year: 2024},Genre->{Game},Title->{ûäL},TrackNumber->{3},TrackTotal->{4}|>|>

In[2]:= ToCharacterCode[{"^ì1G-MSR/¸Ace"}]
IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[{"塞壬唱片-MSR,颜沐宸Ace"}],256]
Out[2]= {{94,236,49,71,45,77,83,82,47,156,144,184,65,99,101}}
Out[3]= {{{88,94},{88,236},{85,49},{114,71},{45},{77},{83},{82},{44},{152,156},{108,144},{91,184},{65},{99},{101}}}

This question is also posted on Wolfram Community.

Finally had time to write a function. If you have any issues, please leave a comment.
FLACMetaInformation[file_] := 
 Module[{marker, bitArray, lastMetadataBlockFlag, metadataBlockType, 
   metadataBlockLength, minimumBlockSize, maximumBlockSize, 
   minimumFrameSize, maximumFrameSize, sampleRate, audioChannels, 
   sampleDepth, length, md5Signature, applicationID, applicationData, 
   vendorLength, vendor, userCommentListLength, userCommentList, 
   userCommentLength, userComment, result},
  Quiet[Close[file]];
  (*the FLAC stream marker*)
  marker = 
   StringJoin[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Character8", 4]]];
  If[marker != "fLaC", Close[file]; Return[$Failed]];
  (*Metadata Block*)
  result = Reap[
     Do[
      bitArray = IntegerDigits[BinaryRead[file], 2, 8];
      lastMetadataBlockFlag = bitArray[[1]];
      metadataBlockType = FromDigits[bitArray[[2 ;; 8]], 2];
      metadataBlockLength = 
       FromDigits[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 3]], 256];
      Sow[Switch[metadataBlockType,
        (*StreamInformation*)
        0, 
        minimumBlockSize = 
         FromDigits[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 2]], 256];
        maximumBlockSize = 
         FromDigits[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 2]], 256];
        minimumFrameSize = 
         FromDigits[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 3]], 256];
        maximumFrameSize = 
         FromDigits[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 3]], 256];
        bitArray = 
         Join @@ IntegerDigits[
           BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 8]], 2, 8];
        sampleRate = FromDigits[bitArray[[1 ;; 20]], 2];
        audioChannels = FromDigits[bitArray[[21 ;; 23]], 2] + 1;
        sampleDepth = FromDigits[bitArray[[24 ;; 28]], 2] + 1;
        length = FromDigits[bitArray[[29 ;; 64]], 2];
        md5Signature = 
         StringJoin @@ 
          IntegerString[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 16]], 
           16];
        <|
         "StreamInformation" -> <|
           "MinimumBlockSize" -> minimumBlockSize, 
           "MaximumBlockSize" -> maximumBlockSize, 
           "MinimumFrameSize" -> minimumFrameSize, 
           "MaximumFrameSize" -> maximumFrameSize, 
           "SampleRate" -> sampleRate, 
           "AudioChannels" -> audioChannels, 
           "SampleDepth" -> sampleDepth, "Length" -> length, 
           "MD5Signature" -> md5Signature|>|>,
        (*Padding*)
        1, 
        BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", metadataBlockLength]];
        Nothing,
        (*Application*)
        2, 
        applicationID = 
         FromCharacterCode[BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", 4]],
           "UTF-8"];
        applicationData = 
         FromCharacterCode[
          BinaryRead[file, 
           ConstantArray["Byte", metadataBlockLength - 4]], "UTF-8"];
        <|
         "Application" -> <|"ApplicationID" -> applicationID, 
           "ApplicationData" -> applicationData|>|>,
        (*SeekTable*)
        3, <|
         "SeekTable" -> (BinaryRead[file, 
            ConstantArray["Byte", metadataBlockLength]]; 
           "I'm lazy...")|>,
        (*VorbisComment*)
        4, vendorLength = BinaryRead[file, "UnsignedInteger32"];
        vendor = 
         FromCharacterCode[
          BinaryRead[file, ConstantArray["Byte", vendorLength]], 
          "UTF-8"];
        userCommentListLength = 
         BinaryRead[file, "UnsignedInteger32"];
        userCommentList = 
         Table[userCommentLength = 
           BinaryRead[file, "UnsignedInteger32"]; 
          userComment = 
           StringSplit[
            FromCharacterCode[
             BinaryRead[file, 
              ConstantArray["Byte", userCommentLength]], "UTF-8"], 
            "=", 2], {i, 1, userCommentListLength}];
        <|
         "VorbisComment" -> <|"Vendor" -> vendor, 
           "UserComment" -> <|Rule @@@ userCommentList|>|>|>,
        5, <|
         "CueSheet" -> 
          BinaryRead[file, 
           ConstantArray["Byte", metadataBlockLength]]|>,
        6, <|
         "Picture" -> (BinaryRead[file, 
            ConstantArray["Byte", metadataBlockLength]]; 
           "I'm lazy...")|>,
        _?(LessEqual[7, #, 126] &), <|
         "Reserved" <> 
           ToString[n] -> (BinaryRead[file, 
            ConstantArray["Byte", metadataBlockLength]]; 
           "I'm lazy...")|>,
        127, Close[file]; Return[$Invalid]]
       ];
      If[lastMetadataBlockFlag == 1, Break[]], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
     ][[2, 1]];
  Return[<|result|>]
  ];

Output example:

